# What does += mean in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net, operators

I tried to google the answer for this but could not find it. I am working on VB.Net. I would like to know what does the operator += mean in VB.Net ?

Comment: As a side note you can also use &= when working with some types in Vb.net. For example foo &= "bar" or foo &= 5 would add either "bar" or 5 to the foo-string. When working in option strict off you can also do Dim a As Integer = 5 a &= 1 which gives 51. But don't do that :D

Comment: is it the equivalent of ++ in java?

Comment: No, it is the equivalent of += in Java. https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Basic_Java_Language#Plus-equals

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It means that you want to add the value to the existing value of the variable.  So, for instance:

```
Dim x As Integer = 1
x += 2  ' x now equals 3
```

In other words, it would be the same as doing this:

```
Dim x As Integer = 1
x = x + 2  ' x now equals 3
```

For future reference, you can see the complete list of VB.NET operators on the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f15ea9k8.aspx).

Answer (score 5):

```
a += b
```

is equivalent to

```
a = a + b
```

In other words, it adds to the current value.

Answer (score 2):

It is plus equals. What it does is take the same variable, adds it with the right hand number (using the + operator), and then assigns it back to the variable. For example,

```
Dim a As Integer
Dim x As Integer
x = 1
a = 1
x += 2
a = a + 2
if x = a then
MsgBox("This will print!")
endif
```

Answer (score 1):

those 2 lines compiled produce the same IL code:

`x += 1`

and

`x = x + 1`

Answer (score 0):

Just makes code more efficient -

```
Dim x as integer = 3
```

`x += 1`

'x = 4

is the same as

`x = x + 1`

'x = 4

It can also be used with a (-):

```
x -= 1
```

' x = 2

Is the same as

```
x = x - 1
```

'x = 2