# Visual Basic Vending Machine

Tags: vb.net, message

I have started work on a Vending Machine code in Visual Basic. It works so far but I wanted it to come up with an error message when you can't afford something. It's still fairly basic with no items on it yet but wanted this to be out of the way before I start with anything else. Currently it's coming up with an error for the "Then" statement and don't know how to fix it. Again im very new to it and aprecate any advise. Thanks.

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub BuyButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BuyButton.Click

    Dim Cost, Amount, Change As Decimal
    Dim Pennies, Pounds As Integer
    Dim msg As String

    Cost = Decimal.Parse(CostTextBox.Text)
    Amount = Decimal.Parse(AmountTextBox.Text)
    Change = (Amount - Cost) * 10

    Pounds = Change \ 10
    Change = Change Mod 10

    Pennies = Change \ 10
    Change = Change Mod 10

    If Change = "Your change is: -" Then

        msg = "You don't have enough Money"

    Else

        msg = "Your change is: " & Change & vbNewLine
        msg += "Pennies: " & Pounds & vbNewLine
        msg += "Pounds: " & Pennies & vbNewLine

    End If

    ChangeLabel.Text = msg

End Sub
End Class
```

Sulution I have used:
Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub BuyButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BuyButton.Click

    Dim Cost, Amount, Change As Decimal
    Dim Pennies, Pounds As Integer
    Dim msg As String

    Cost = Decimal.Parse(CostTextBox.Text)
    Amount = Decimal.Parse(AmountTextBox.Text)
    Change = (Amount - Cost)

    If Change < 0 Then

        msg = "You don't have enough Money"
        AmountTextBox.Text = Change + Cost

    Else

        AmountTextBox.Text = Change
        Pounds = Math.Floor(Change)
        Pennies = (Change - Pounds) * 100

        msg = "Your change is: " & Change.ToString("##.00") & Environment.NewLine
        msg += "Pounds: " & Pounds & vbNewLine
        msg += "Pennies: " & Pennies & vbNewLine

    End If
    ChangeLabel.Text = msg
End Sub
```

Comment: I have tried that but no it will only display the message now.
        If Change < 10 Then
            msg = "You don't have enougth Money"
        Else

Comment: If Change < 0 Then "Code here" Else "Code here" End If

Comment: I'm sorry but It still dosen't work, It will either allow anything or nothing.

Comment: okay first thing to do is break down the problem, use msgbox before the if statement to see what value is present for the change MsgBox(change), to help i need more than "it doesnt work"

Comment: I'm sorry, like I said im very new to this. I have put a MsgBox(Change) before the If Statement, the text that shows the change stays the same as before but the number in the box that pops up displays 0, no matter what numbers are enterd.
        MsgBox(Change)
        If Change < 1 Then
            msg = "You don't have enougth Money"
        Else

Comment: Seems like VB Vending machines are popular nowadays: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23542297/visual-basic-vending-machine?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

First, to check if there's enough money, you check if change is less than 0 - `If  Change <0 Then ...`. Second, you are changing `Change` with `Change = Change mod 10`, so at the end you won't get correct result. Third, it is easier to make Change a integer. To get last two digits of change(pennies), you should use `Pennies=Change mod 100`, and to get other digits(pounds), you should use `Pounds=Change\100`. Fourth, you swapped pounds and pennies while creating message. And last, you only need to split the change to pounds and pennies if there is change.

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub BuyButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BuyButton.Click

    Dim Amount, Change As Decimal
    Dim Cost, Pennies, Pounds As Integer
    Dim msg As String

    Cost = Decimal.Parse(CostTextBox.Text)
    Amount = Decimal.Parse(AmountTextBox.Text)
    Change = (Amount - Cost) * 100

    If Change < 0 Then

        msg = "You don't have enough Money"

    Else

        Pounds = Change \ 100
        Pennies = Change Mod 100
        msg = "Your change is: " & Change & vbNewLine
        msg += "Pounds: " & Pounds & vbNewLine
        msg += "Pennies: " & Pennies & vbNewLine

    End If

    ChangeLabel.Text = msg

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thank you for a fully writen answer, this thow dosn't work with pennies in the message at the end. It desplays 0, thats saying the anmouts entered use 00.90 for example for 90p. Is there away around this?

Comment: Oh, I didn't check your logic for calculating pounds and pennies. I edited answer, it should work now.

Comment: That's because you set `Pennies = Change Mod 10` and then divide that by 10 again. Once you do the `Mod` you are left with your change in units of 10, therefore you must multiply by 10. Dividing by 10 gives you a number under 1 and the implicit conversion from `Decimal` to `Int` rounds that down.

Comment: Thank you, Iv'e changed the \ 100 to \ 10 because it was creating a number to big in the "Your Change is:" line. There is still 1 too many 0's in it thow, iv'e tryed it with \ 1 but it dosn't change it. Any help?

Comment: My bad, it should be *100, not *1000. I edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I'd look at streamlining this a bit. Stop dividing by 10 and multiplying by 10 - it's not helpful to your cause. Go for something like this.

```vb
Dim Cost, Amount, Change As Decimal
    Dim Pennies, Pounds As Integer
    Dim msg As String

    Cost = Decimal.Parse(CostTextBox.Text)
    Amount = Decimal.Parse(AmountTextBox.Text)
    Change = (Amount - Cost)  --Work in pounds

    If Change < 0 Then

        msg = "You don't have enough Money"

    Else

        Pounds = Math.Floor(Change)
        Pennies = (Change - Pounds) * 100  --Multiply pounds by 100 to get pence

        --Environment.NewLine is the preferred way to insert a newline which will
        --always be correct for the environment.
        msg = "Your change is: " & Change.ToString("##.00") & Environment.NewLine --Note the .ToString("##.00") - this tells VB to convert the number to a string and show two decimal places
        msg += "Pounds: " & Pounds.ToString() & Environment.NewLine
        msg += "Pennies: " & Pennies.ToString() & Environment.NewLine

    End If

    ChangeLabel.Text = msg
```

Avoid implicit conversions at all costs. Yes, `Pounds = Change / 10` works, but it is an implicit narrowing and may not work how you expect it to. The reason we use `Math.Floor` here is because we want the integer portion of the decimal and that's what `Math.Floor` does - gives you the largest whole number that is equal to or less than the supplied value.

Also note the use of the `Change.ToString` - all intrinsic types are derived from the super-type `Object` which means they implement the method ToString. This will give you an explicitly converted string representation of the value of the object to which you can apply formatting by supplying a mask (the `"##.00#"`bit in the parentheses). [Have a look at the MSDNpage on the subject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to see more about applying custom formats to strings.

Comment: No worries. Handling strings and number is fundamental to any programming so it's worth taking the time to get it right to start with. Avoid implicit conversions and you'll save yourself a lot of trouble at some point in the future, I guarantee you!

Comment: Also, note that your routine will be borked if someone puts 'xyz' into the textboxes - always check your inputs and reject bad data. Crap data in = crap data out, if you're lucky!

Comment: Thanks for your help, if you could help me with ths aswell I would be very greatfull. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23410436/visual-basic-button-with-a-value

Answer (score 0):

```
If Change = "Your change is: -" Then
```

the change value should equate to a value, and not to a string this will need to be changed to something like

`If change < 0 Then`

normally when i am contatinating string i use the `&` operator,in not too sure if the =+ version works (i've never tried it)

```
msg = msg &  "Pennies: " & Pounds & vbNewLine
msg = msg & "Pounds: " & Pennies & vbNewLine
```

Comment: in .NET [the `+=` works just fine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693984/what-does-mean-in-visual-basic)