# Visual Basic Button with a Value

Tags: vb.net, button, textbox

Im new to this etc, and I was woundering if you can make a button equal a value once clicked. Heres what Iv'e got for an exmple:

Public Class Form1

```
    Private Sub BuyButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BuyButton.Click

        Dim MoneyBtn1 As String
        Btn10p.PerformClick = MoneyBtn1
        MoneyBtn1 = 0.1 + AmountTextBox.Text

        Dim Cost, Amount, Change As Decimal
        Dim Pennies, Pounds As Integer
        Dim msg As String

        Cost = Decimal.Parse(CostTextBox.Text)
        Amount = Decimal.Parse(AmountTextBox.Text)
        Change = (Amount - Cost)

        If Change < 0 Then

            msg = "You don't have enough Money"

        Else

            Pounds = Math.Floor(Change)
            Pennies = (Change - Pounds) * 100

            msg = "Your change is: " & Change.ToString("##.00") & Environment.NewLine
            msg += "Pounds: " & Pounds & vbNewLine
            msg += "Pennies: " & Pennies & vbNewLine

        End If
        ChangeLabel.Text = msg
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer I have used:
  Private Sub Btn10p_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Btn10p.Click
        AmountTextBox.Text = AmountTextBox.Text + 0.1
    End Sub

Comment: A couple of tips. Put your code in a code block (highlight it and press cntl+k). Also, is this vb.net or vba? They are different languages. Please edit your question so you can receive attention from the correct people.

Comment: Or resist edits intended to help you by rolling them back. :}

Comment: What is the purpose / meaning of `make a button equal a value`? What are you trying to achieve? Buttons are there for a purpose and it is to fire an event after a click, not to be used as a variable to hold a random value. Event though your variable has a `btn` in its name, this does not make the variable a button! So your `MoneyBtn` is a string holding *text*, not a button.

Comment: I'm trying to make a button that every time it's clicked, it adds set number onto another number in a textbox. Every time its click it adds it on again.

Comment: Use the `Click` event. Please paste your complete code. You need to create a callback method / delegate that handles the `Click` event and in this event handler you can sum the amount and save it into the variable.

Comment: Thanks, Iv'e edited the first post to have the full code in.

Comment: Bit cheeky to use the [code I suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23409807/60602) verbatim (without fixing the deliberate omissions which means you didn't really read and understand the comments!), not accept or vote up the answer then ask for help with this...

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Beside the first three lines in the click event, everything else seems good.

Comment: @StevePettifer this explains the current question and the new code...

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the text on a button? Or do you simply want more than one click event to perform the same increment routine? If the latter then

```
Private Sub BuyButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BuyButton.Click

    IncrementValue()

    --Other stuff.

End Sub

Private Sub SomeOtherButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SomeOtherButton.Click
    IncrementValue()
End Sub

Private Sub IncrementValue()
    TextBox.Text = (Decimal.Parse(TextBox.Text) + 0.1).ToString
End Sub
```

If that's not what you're after then you need to explain exactly what you want in better detail.