# UWP Xbox One Disable Mouse in VB (NOT C#)

Tags: c#, vb.net, uwp, xbox-one

I have read over documents stating that for optimal Xbox One experience, I should disable Mouse Mode in my application. This makes absolute sense. all of the examples are in C# though, and m,y language of choice is unfortunately Visual Basic.

The C# code is:

```
public App() {
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.RequiresPointerMode = ApplicationRequiresPointerMode.WhenRequested;
    this.Suspending += OnSuspending;
}
```

I can translate the code to VB without an issue except for the last statement.

I seem to be stumped on the line: `Me.Suspending += Me.OnSuspending`

How might I translate this, and move forward with my development?

I'm at a road block and feel pretty dumb, because I should know how to do this.

EDIT: Even when changing the code to `Me.Suspending = Me.Suspending + Me.OnSuspending` the same raiseevent error is thrown. So therefor, this is NOT a duplicate, because I am well aware of how a `+=` operator works.

Comment: VB.NET uses same `+=` operator for assignment too. It is equal to `Me.Suspending = Me.Suspending + Me.OnSuspending`. Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693984/what-does-mean-in-visual-basic.

Comment: Wow, I completely overlooked that! Thanks.

Comment: While it does still function the same, the modification of the code you suggested still throws an error as I described above.

Comment: You need `AddHandler` for example `AddHandler Me.Suspending, AddressOf OnSuspending`... Also make sure to remove the handler as well when you are done...

Comment: Also this was kind of a dup, but not the one mentioned above. @Tetsuya Yamamoto has a trigger finger and `+=` is **not for handler assignment in vb.net**. The `+=` simply adds the value to an existing value of a variable.